# Different submit button at the same PHP page

Tags: php, form-submit

I want to ask about a way to use more than a submit button at one same page 
here are the process: first the user make a choice from the select list and click valid then an array will be shown with another action

[image: first senario]

[image: second senario]

the problem is that only the first submit button is active but the second one don't work

Comment: how many forms in this page?

Comment: there is  one  form

Comment: one form form only for the select list

Comment: hmm that is a problem you have to set 2 forms for 2 different actions

Comment: i see but what about the actions ? cause there are both at the same page :(

Comment: you first list box button click then show list to bottom so this is a first action and bottom lists any changes and done so that is second action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax GET request by clicking a first button, and append elements for second POST request who is form with submit button. But if you want to use two submits you must have two forms or only way  to do this is if two forms is equal.
**AND IS TOTALLY WRONG TO MAKE SQL QUERY FROM HTML !!!** 
**edited**

***example***

```
  $('#selectbox1').change(function() { var data = ""; $.ajax({ 
    type:"GET", 
    url : "controller mapping", 
    data : "selectbox1_selectedvalue="+$(this).val(), 
    async: false,
     success : function(response) { 
    data = response; 
    return response; 
    }, 
    error: function() { 
    alert('Error occured');
     } 
    }); 
    var string = data.message.split(","); 
    var array = string.filter(function(e){
return e;
});
  $.each(array, function(index, value) {
    //here it's your form with inputs.
    $('#form').append("<input name="inputName" value="value"/>");
     }); 
    $('#form').show()
    });
```

---

> this is on select change

---

Comment: Oh i see please i would be so greatful if you show me a way to use it with ajax, i really need that so much for my work
if you can just give a litlle exemple for that in AJAX 
And thak you so much

Comment: I added ajax example please see it.

Comment: Thank you so much   Dimitar Manovski  !!

Answer (score 0):

One form, can only have one submit. So if you want two submits, create two forms.

Comment: i've did but the second submit button is not working :( only the first one got a value but second  one stills empty

Comment: Put the source code up here so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //here is the first code for the select list


<header class="panel-heading ">
                                <form action="index2.php" method="post" name="a">          <!-- first form  for the select list-->
                                    <fieldset> 
                                       Veuillez selectionnez un chantier : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                     <select name="chantier" class=" dropdown-toggle"> 
                                            <option value="NULL">-- Selectionner --</option> 
                                            <?php 

                                    include"config.php";
                                     $str = $_SESSION['username'] ; 

                                    $query = " SELECT dbo.CH_PROTUSER.CH_Designation, dbo.CH_PROTUSER.CH_Num, 
                                    dbo.CH_ACCES.U_Login FROM dbo.CH_PROTUSER INNER JOIN dbo.CH_ACCES ON
                                    dbo.CH_PROTUSER.CH_Num = dbo.CH_ACCES.U_CHNUM Where dbo.CH_ACCES.U_Login= '$str' ";
                                    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
                                    while( $rs = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $rs['CH_Num'];   "<option id='". $rs['CH_Num'] ."'>"?>" ><?php echo $rs['CH_Designation'] ?></option> <?php }
                                    $s=($_POST['chantier']);
                                    echo $s;
                                     ?>
                                </select>

                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <input type="submit"  value="Valider"  class="btn btn-success btn-xs " i class="fa fa-check"></i>

                                    </fieldset> 
                                </form>
                            </header>
```

//here is the second code for the second form which is at the array

```
           echo' <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading ">
                            Resultats
                        </header>
                        <table class="table responsive-data-table data-table">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><center>CodeMDP</center></th>
                                    <th><center>Matricule</center></th>
                                    <th><center>Prenom</center></th>
                                    <th><center>Nom</center></th>
                                    <th><center>H.Norm</center></th>
                                    <th><center>H.DIV</center></th>
                                    <th><center>H.Supp</center></th>
                                    <th><center>Dimanche</center></th>
                                    <th><center>Ferier</center></th>
                                    <th><center> Modfier</center> </th>
                                    <th><center> Suprrimer</center> </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>';

                                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){

                                    $xss =$row['P_MATRICULE'];

                                        echo "<tr><td>" .'<center>' . $row['P_CODECHT'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_MATRICULE'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_PRENOM'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>"  .'<center>'. $row['P_NOM'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_HNORM'] .'</center>'. "</td> 
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_HEURDIV'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_HEURSUP'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_HDIMANCH'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>" .'<center>'. $row['P_HFERIER'] .'</center>'. "</td>
                                        <td>  <form action='' method='post' name='b'> " ."<center><button data-toggle='modal' Type='submit' name='xyz'  
                                        value='$xss' class=' btn btn-info' href='#myModal' ><i class='fa  fa-pencil' ></i></center> ". "</form></td>
                                        <td>" ."<center><button data-toggle='button' class=' btn btn-danger' name='xyz'  ><i class='fa fa-trash-o' ></i></button></center> ". "</td>
                                            </tr>"; 
                                        }   
                                         if(isset($_POST['xyz'])) { 
                                             echo"aa";
                                        $sss="$xss";
                                        $query2 = " SELECT P_HNORM,P_HEURDIV,P_HDIMANCH,P_HFERIER,P_HEURSUP
                                        FROM [C_POINTAGESEMPLOYE] WHERE P_MATRICULE = '$sss'  AND (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), P_DATETX, 12) 
                                         AS [MM-DD-YY])   = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 12) AS [MM-DD-YY])";
                                          $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2);
                                          while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
                                        {
                                        $hn =($row2['P_HNORM']);
                                        $hd =($row2['P_HEURDIV']);
                                        $hs =($row2['P_HEURSUP']);
                                        $hdim =($row2['P_HDIMANCH']);
                                        $hf =($row2['P_HFERIER']);
                                        }
                                         }

                                    echo'
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                    </section>

                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                     <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading ">                        
                            <p align="right">                      
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success "><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Confirmer </button>
                            </p>

                        </header>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>' ;
```